# Inexpensive image editing software to add nice arrows

Tags: images, software-recommendation, image-editing, arrow

I am working on some support articles, and I would like to add some example screenshots, and in those screenshots, I would like to add large arrows where the border color is different than the fill color, so it looks more engaging and fun (you can see some examples [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYG4B.png), made using Google Slides). Google Drawings is fine, but the images end up looking a bit blurry when I go to export, and I want these images to be as clear as possible for the article. Is there a good app someone can recommend? The only requirements are:

1. It works on both Mac and PC (or it's a web app).
2. It can import images that can be edited, and export the modified image without reducing the quality.
3. It can add arrow shapes with customizable fill and border colors.

I've looked at dozens of apps, and I thought most of them would be able to do this, but this is surprisingly rare.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You dont actually want a image editor. You want a vector application. Try inkscape.

Comment: [Figma](https://www.figma.com/) probably... Though I don't know if the [importable formats](https://help.figma.com/hc/en-us/articles/360041003114-Import-files-into-Figma#Drag_and_Drop_Files) are enough for your needs... Or if it's possible to edit imported images to the degree you want. If they are svg files then probably yes, but if it's like that png you posted, it would have to be redrawn... which would be very easy in Figma.

Comment: Unless I am missing something, it looks like Inkscape and Figma don't have those arrows.

Comment: Not trying to be super pedantic here, but you didn't specify how you wanted to "add arrows". Any proper image editing application can add arrows one way or another, though they have to be vector in order to edit the border and color easily. If you're thinking of some sort of clipart arrow stamper, you might have to find a plugin for an application... But importing images isn't really that time consuming.

Comment: All you have to do is google "Free svg arrow" or try a stock photo website like [shutter stock](https://www.shutterstock.com/fi/search/arrow?image_type=vector) or maybe [Freepik](https://www.freepik.com/search?format=search&query=arrow&type=vector) or [Creative market](https://creativemarket.com/search?q=arrow&files=31&sort=relevant). I searched specifically for vector, but that doesn't always mean svg, which is the only vector format figma supports.

Comment: Inkscape can import any vector format you should care about, but there are for example online converters from eps or pdf to svg though I wouldn't necessarily buy images in the wrong format and just trust that I can convert them without any issues. But yea to wrap up this fat multipart comment, [here's an import / edit example in figma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Frduq.gif). The svg came out horrible, but [this is the png I exported](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1a0v6.png).

Comment: I reread the question and I seemingly forgot that you ever mentioned screenshots and just focused on how you were asking for image editing application suggestions (in a graphic design SE site) and wanted to edit the border. I mean what I've said so far is valid, but if you are annotating screenshots, I'm almost certain any annotation software would be way better for your use case... At least if you're willing to let go of the idea that you absolutely need to add a very specific style arrow and/or modify its border. Maybe look into [Snagit](https://techsmith.com/blog/tutorials/snagit/arrow).

Answer (score 0):

A fat arrow is a specific type of shape. A shape of a fat arrow with a border and with fill. But they are not very flexible. That is why not every software incorporates them in a library.

What you can do in almost any vector-based software is stack two arrows, curved, fat, thin, etc. One is the fill, and the other one fatter is the border.

In the end, what you need is a vector-based program.

Your "only" requirements are not simple. Are specific to (drums here) a vector-based program.

Inkscape is free (cheap enough) and if you can not find a fat arrow in a library, do as I said.

I do not know what is your concept of the app. An app sounds to me like a small program that runs on your phone. One that runs on a browser is Gravit Designer free: https://www.designer.io/en/offers/freegravit/

> but the images end up looking a bit blurry when I go to export

This is something you need to address on any software. Make the export resolution exactly match your background image.

The three paid software recommendations are Adobe Illustrator, Corel Draw, and Affinity Designer.

Comment: "App" is short for "application", and it is pretty much any service that runs on a computer, whether it is a desktop app or a web app.

Unfortunately, it looks like Gravit does not have those large arrows.